# Why is there always a dash in my title tag

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

in my aspx page I haeve

```
<%@ Page Title="sdvd" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/BannerLink/BannerLinkAdmin.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="TwilioNumbers.aspx.vb" Inherits="BannerLink_TwilioNumbers" %>
```

I want "sdvd" to show up in the tab on my browser. But for some reason the tab has "sdvd -" Why is the dash there?

Edit: As  HaukurHaf asked here is the head area in the master page

```
<head runat="server">
<title>LiquidusTV - Admin</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="admin.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="icon" href="admin.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<link href="Styles/Admin.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"  src="Scripts/Web.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript">   </script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $(".fancy").fancybox({
         'width': 918,
         'height': 700,
         'autoScale': false,
         'transitionIn': 'none',
         'transitionOut': 'none',
         'type': 'iframe'             
     });
 });

 function openFancy(url) {
     $("#hidden_link").attr("href", url);
     $("#hidden_link").trigger('click');
     return false;
 }
 </script>
<style type="text/css">
#hidden_link { display: none; }
</style>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

Comment: Show us the head section of your BannerLinkAdmin.master page.

Comment: Maybe it's a browser thing. Does it do that in all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper format I think you need to remove runat from head tag.

```
<head>
    <title runat="server" id="PageTitle"></title>
</head>
```

In the Code behind you can add:

```
   PageTitle.InnerHtml = "sdvd"
```

Answer (score 0):

The title in the browser does not come from the `<%@ Page %>` "tag". It comes from the `<title>` tag in the `<head>` section.

Try removing the `<title>` from the page and see what happens.

From the documentation on [`Page.Title`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.page.title.aspx):

> The page must contain a head element that has the attribute runat="server", otherwise the title will not render.

You have such a `<head runat="server">` element, but I bet that ASP.NET doesn't override the `<title>` you manually put on your page.

Also, I suggest you do a "View Source" to see if maybe *both* `<title>` elements are present. A browser would have to pick one of the two.

Comment: Hey I tried that earlier with, <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <title>sdvd</title> i didnt work in changing the title in the browser

Comment: First, determine which HTML is being sent to the browser. Only ff that doesn't clear things up will you have to worry about how the browser is treating what is sent to it.

Comment: If you have a head element with runat="server" in a master page and a "content" page using that master page has a title attribute in the @page directive, then that is indeed the title that gets output in the title tag in the final output.  Or am I wrong?

Comment: I recommend removing the `<title>` from the master page and then see what happens.